# Images Aren't Showing Unless Page is Refreshsed

Tags: html, image

My client has a very simple HTML website. A few of the images are having loading issues. They only load entirely once you've refreshed the page. The problem areas are the 'Sponsors' section (the logos near the bottom of the page), and sometimes the 'What's Included' section.

What I've Tried:

- At first I thought it was an SVG issue so I exported them as PNGs – didn't make a difference
- I've checked console to ensure there were no issues causing the page to stop rendering half way down
- I've double checked the image size to ensure fast download. All are KBs.

It's such a basic site, I've never ran into this issue before. I'm stumped.

[Click here to view website](http://hohoholiday5k.com/)

Comment: have you tried viewing the site on different devices? How do you know the issue isn't with your specific system or browser? Have you done a ***hard*** refresh (`Ctrl`+`F5`)?

Comment: I went on your site and everything loaded correctly on `Linux Mint` using `Chrome v62`. The only error that I saw was facebook SDK related. The page also loads correctly on `Firefox v57`. Nice site design btw.

Comment: I saw a couple of sponsor logos load, and then the rest loaded later. I peeked at your source and see that the sponsor logos have width attributes specified with "px" - they should just be numbers (no px). Not sure if that's the problem but you could try and fix that.

Comment: This is so odd... I disabled extensions, disabled javascript, and disabled cache to test this and I was able to reproduce it.  It looks like Chrome is struggling to paint the viewport on initial load.  A repaint (like when you resize the browser) "corrects" it, but until then, it just can't handle it. Demo: https://i.imgur.com/R9SmcrD.gifv.  Are you able to rasterize those SVG logos?  Try replacing them with PNG files of a reasonable size and see if that helps it at all.

Comment: Well, I didn't read that carefully.  I see you already tried my idea of replacing the SVGs.   Sorry for wasting time there.  Can you systematically remove each section (`.subheader`, `.about-section`, `.obstacles-section` on down the line) and try to reproduce the issue to narrow down which section is causing the behavior?

Comment: @martin – I emailed my client and had them test on their end to ensure it wasn't a network issue on my end – they're still seeing this issue. I tried on Chrome, FF and Safari and I'm on a Mac. I also tested on Chrome on the PC Surface Pro 2 and it does not show all the sponsor logos on load, or the what's included illustrations. 

However, I do not see the issue on mobile on iOS.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Locally I can't reproduce the issue, everything loads smooth and easy. :(

Comment: @stackingjasoncooper Good eye, I fixed that up but sadly that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: [**Use the Firefox page developer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) to explore what's going on with your page. You're currently loading *114* elements for this page, that's rather a lot.... I think....